# How should I handle a json field which can be either an object or a string?

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using GSON to deserialize json data. Now, the data has an oddity in which a certain field may be either an empty string or an object (it's a nested tree-like structure of similar objects). How should this be handled?

The json looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "data": {
            "foo": "bar",
            "child": ""            <-- If no children
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "foo": "baz",
            "child": {            <-- If a child
                "foo": "bat",
                "child": ""
            }
        }
    },
]
```

The POJO looks like this:

```
public class Data {
    private String foo;
    private Data child;
}
```

And when trying to deserialize a json and the `child` field is `""`, the exception thrown is:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
```

Comment: Depends what you want to achieve. You can threat is as null value for example or abnormal situation. Your question needst to be more precise.

Comment: @Antoniossss I'd prefer the field to be null if it's a string, and deserialize the object if it's not a string.

Comment: But this is most common behavior you can ever met. If you are using GSON it should be handled automaticly

Comment: It's not. If the field is not declared as transient, GSON will crash with "expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING" error.

Comment: Dont mark is as transient - do you even know what does it mean? You should mark is as nullable object of required type. Besides, you should paste stacktrace and ann the stuff related to this case.

Comment: @Antoniossss It is marked correctly (a nullable object of the required type), and I do know what transient means. In this case, GSON tries to deserialize a string as it sees "" there, but the field is not a string.

Comment: Show us the object mapping and exception - nothing to do here without any of those

Comment: @Antoniossss Added code and the exception.

Comment: @manabreak your issue solved?

Comment: @skadoosh I did solve it a bit differently, although my solution does not answer the question so I won't post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a GSON expert and I am using `Jackson` myself but it looks like that you will have to use either custom type adapter or deserializer. Something similar has been done here

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-gson/kNf5HADtY14 for a `Long` and `Integer` types.

I guess you will have to adopt provided solution to suit your needs.

Moreover, requested behaviour has been reported as missing feature/bug here https://github.com/google/gson/issues/540, and as the resulition `TypeAdapter` is suggested to be suited to do the job

Comment: This doesn't help me at all.

Answer (score 0):

use `Object` as type for your `child` field, you will need to implement different strategies to handle the different types the `child` field can be in the code where you're using your deserialized `Data` instances

```
public class Data {
    private String foo;
    private Object child;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While reading `JsonElement` `child` you need to check what **kind of object** it is, I mean check whether its a `JsonObject` or `String(or any Primitive data type)`

```
    JsonArray response = your_array_response;
    for (int i = 0; i < response.size(); i++) {

        JsonObject object = response.get(i).getAsJsonObject();

        JsonObject dataObject = object.get("data").getAsJsonObject();
        JsonElement element = dataObject.get("child");

        if (element.isJsonObject()) {
            JsonObject childObject = element.getAsJsonObject();
            System.out.println("JsonObject : Foo = "+childObject.get("foo").getAsString());
        } else if (element.isJsonPrimitive()) {
            System.out.println("A String: value = " + element.getAsString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'd like to see the solution where you get the actual result, i.e. the root object you can traverse. Your solution doesn't yet tell how to produce that.